# Normal subgroup notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup, then it is standard to say that $H$ is normal in $G$ if and only if for all $x \in G$, $xHx^{-1} \subseteq H$. My question here is, if $G$ and $H$ are additive groups, it is okay notation to write $x + H + x^{-1}$? Or is this something that is not done.

Comment: In this case you should denote the inverse by $(-x)$, not $x^{-1}$.

Comment: Oh yes indeed. But is the notation acceptable? Or is it better off to use the multiplication notation even though i am referring to additive groups .

Comment: If the group is additive then we indeed write $+$. But remember that when we call the operation addition, we usually mean the group is abelian, and in this case every subgroup is normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any binary operation $\ast$ that defines a group $G$ with a subgroup (or even a subset) $H$, it is acceptable to write

$$x\ast H\ast x^{-1}=\{ x\ast h\ast x^{-1}\mid h\in H\}$$

for any $x\in G$. This is due to the associativity of $\ast$. Note that $x^{-1}$ is *with respect to $\ast$*, so if $\ast=+$, then use $-x$.

Answer (score 3):

As Mark [points out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988852/normal-subgroup-notation#comment8231265_3988852) [in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988852/normal-subgroup-notation#comment8231276_3988852), it would be more appropriate to write $x+H+(-x)$ in such a case, but we typically use the additive notation for abelian groups, in which case every subgroup is normal, so we wouldn't bother to write it.